# Хочу чтобы в LoginView в случаее неверности пароля , программа писала об этом

Tags: html, css, python, django, auth

Что то по типу не верный пароль но не могу решить как это сделать , во view нечего нету не писал я просто использовал готовый метод django auth LoginView

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from . import views


urlpatterns =[
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path(r'login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html', success_url='news/'), name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('accounts/profile/', views.indexs, name='indexs'),

]
```

views.py

```
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, LoginForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        context = {
                   'username': username,
                   'password1': password1,
                   'password2': password2,
                   'email': email}

        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            return render(request, 'registration/registred.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/registred.html')


def indexs(request):
    return render(request,'ShapeHtml/MainShape.html')
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password1'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']
```

Comment: Если совпадают пароли у разных логинов??? да пусть совпадают, твоя-то какая печаль?

Comment: Ты не понял пороли не совподают при вводе их там пороль и повторите пороль

Comment: Я полностью переписал ответ. 3 Ваших вопроса были слиты воедино. Код только что проверил, он полностью работоспособен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Регистрация

Для начала нам нужна форма.
Я не стал изобретать велосипед, в Django уже есть `UserCreationForm`. Будем отталкиваться от неё.

Единственный недостаток, у пользователей может быть одинаковый email, поэтому мы добавим метод для его проверки

***forms.py:***

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Posts.models import Post


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].strip()
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('')

        return email
```

---

Форма готова, теперь представление.
Думаю, было бы хорошо, чтобы выводились ошибки, но данные не стирались. То есть, будем сохранять весь контекст.

Вот простой пример:

***views.py:***

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm


# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        context = {'form': form,
                   'username': username,
                   'password1': password1,
                   'password2': password2,
                   'email': email}

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        context = {'form': form
                   }

    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

---

Осталось подставить наш контекст и вывести ошибки, если они есть. Я буду выводить все сразу, но можно и для конкретного поля с помощью такой инструкции: `form.name_of_field.errors`

Пример:

***register.html:***

```html
...
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.errors }}
{% endfor %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username }}">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ email }}">
    <input type="password" name="password1" value="{{ password1 }}">
    <input type="password" name="password2" value="{{ password2 }}">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Регистрация">
</form>
...
```

---

Привяжем это к URL:

***urls.py:***

```py
from django.urls import path
from core.views import register


urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    ...
]
```

Теперь пользователи регистрируются после валидации данных. Если данные невалидны, то в шаблон передаётся ошибка.

### Авторизация

Для авторизации мы воспользуемся готовым представлением `LoginView`

***urls.py***

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
...


urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
]
```

---

Осталось вывести ошибки в шаблон.
Но теперь нет конкретного поля с ошибкой. Мы не знаем, ошибся пользователь паролем или же логином. Для таких ошибок есть специальное название `non_field_errors`.

Пример:

***login.html:***

```html
...
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти">
</form>
...
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <p>Вы ввели неверные данные</p>
{% endif %}
```

---

Рекомендую почитать:

1. [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/)
2. [Django формы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/)
3. [Шаблонизатор Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/)

*Примечание: Ответ был полностью переписан, так как были заданы 3 идентичных вопроса по этим темам. Было принято решение слить их воедино для упрощения поиска информации и прекращения копирования одинаковых участков кода для связи.*