# Хочу сделать чтобы при вводе пароля и повтора пароля если они совпадали писало об этом

Tags: html, css, python, django

К примеру вводите вы пароль "картошка" а при повтори допустили ошибку "картофка" и об этом написало что то вроде "пороли не совпадают попробуйте еще раз" и пожалуйста распешите все подробнее я просто тупой.

И просьба чтобы не получалось что то вроде выводилось error#r124215 а нормальный понятный текст в шаблон "У вас не совпадают пороли"

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.db import models


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')



class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

views.py

```
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, LoginForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        context = {
                   'username': username,
                   'password1': password1,
                   'password2': password2,
                   'email': email}

        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            return render(request, 'registration/registred.html', {'new_user': new_user})

    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/registred.html')


def indexs(request):
    return render(request,'ShapeHtml/MainShape.html')
```

registred.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
  <h1>регистрация</h1> <br>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h3>Логин</h3> <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username }}"> <br>
  <h3>Почта</h3> <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ email }}"> <br>
  <h3>Пароль</h3> <input type="password" name="password1" value="{{ password1 }}"> <br>
  <h3>Повторите пароль</h3> <input type="password" name="password2" value="{{ password2 }}"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Войти">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Кажется, я уже этот код наизусть знаю. Он мне снится будет. Это третий Ваш полностью одинаковый вопрос за день :). Удивляет меня то, что мои прошлые ответы Вы приняли, а код из раз в раз не меняется. Анекдот какой-то... [первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/991364/Проверка-на-несовпадение-пароля-или-существование-логина/991377#991377), [второй](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/991005/Хочу-чтобы-в-loginview-в-случаее-неверности-пароля-программа-писала-об-этом/991023#991023)